# Error when enlarging a LUKS encrypted partition with Gparted

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted, luks

I'm having trouble locating up to date resources for this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have an Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox, and used the vboxmanage modifyhd command to increase the size of the VM. I booted into an Ubuntu live CD and was able see the new unallocated space in Gparted. I  increased the size of the extended partition (sda2) and then after decrypting and deactivating the sd5 partition, I assigning all the unallocated space to it.

When I try to apply the changes I get the following error:

> cryptsetup -v resize 'sda5_crypt'
>
> command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters)
>
> nothing to read on input

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm running Gparted 0.33.0 which is the latest on apt.

Comment: Also encountering the same error when using the latest version of Gparted live CD.

Answer (score 3):

Current version of gparted (1.1.0) does not support LUKS2 format (which is used in recent linux versions). See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/issues/59

A workaround is to use partitionmanager (from KDE) instead of gparted : in a liveCD/liveUSB session, you need to enable the Universe repository (inside  "Applications and updates"), then install `partitionmanager` package.

If you start partitionmanager, you can unlock the encrypted partition, and resize it.

I tested that inside a VM and it worked. But I sometimes got errors when applying the changes in partitionmanager, because it tried to run the following incorrect command-line :

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/luks-b3197c62-7ae8-4732-a16c-d6d0ad9114f2 -2234368s
```

I suppose it's a bug in partitionmanager.

However, I did the same resizing again, applied it again, and it worked.

Comment: Saved my day! I've also got an error first time, but on second try the partition was finally reduced without errors and I could reboot into my machine without loosing any data to my surprise! Though the first reboot after shrinking took a bit longer and threw an error about not being able to find the volume group, but than somehow everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue running Gparted 1.0.0 on Parrot 4.8. It seems that the problem is that `cryptsetup resize` asks for the encryption passphrase and gparted is not expecting that.

Try running the `sudo cryptsetup -v resize 'sda5_crypt'` command manually in a shell instead of through gparted.

If you need to shrink the partition I think you would need to do the entire process manually on the command line (`cryptsetup luksOpen`, `resize2fs`, `cryptsetup resize`, `cryptsetup close`, `parted`).